# Netty: Secure connection without using certificates

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, netty

I'm looking for a solution to transmit data from server to client (and vice versa) securely. I.e. that the data can't be read by a 3rd person.

I found that a secure connection between server and client can be established using an SSLHandler, which has to be added to the channel pipeline. An SSLEngine is passed as a parameter and it is created by the SSLContext, which contains the key- and truststore.

Since I don't care who connects to the server (it has already been assured, that the client is a verified client) I'm looking for a solution without certificates.

Is it possible to create a secure connection without using certificates?

Comment: SSL needs a certificate. What about a self-signed certificate? Should do the job for your use case. Or you could use http://www.startssl.com/ - there you can get free certificates.

Comment: Without certificates, how does the _client_ know its connecting to the correct _server_?

Comment: Just use selfsigned certificates then. The problem with home-brew encryption systems is that they will almost certainly suck. As [Bruce Schneier stated it:](https://www.schneier.com/essays/archives/1998/01/security_pitfalls_in.html) `Building a secure cryptographic system is easy to do badly, and very difficult to do well. Unfortunately, most people can't tell the difference.`

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. SSL needs a certificate. But it does not have to be verifiable by a authority (if the client doesn't check it) - so you can use a self-signed certificate. Should do the job for your use case. Or you could use startssl.com - there you can get free certificates.